# How does java handle integer overflow and underflow?

Tags: java

i know this is an old question, asked many times. but i am not able to find any satisfactory answer for this, hence asking again.
can someone explain what exactly happens in case of integer overflow and underflow?
**i have heard about some 'lower order bytes' which handle this, can someone explain what is that?**

thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could imagine that when you have only 2 places you are counting (so adding 1 each time)

```
 00
 01
 10
 11 
100
```

But the last one gets cut down to "00" again. So there is your "overflow". You're back at 00. Now depending on what the bits mean, this can mean several things, but most of the time this means you are going from the highest value to the lowest. (11 to 00)

Mark peters adds a good one in the comments: even without overflow you'll have a problem, because the first bit is used as signing, so you'll go from high to low without losing that bit. You could say that the bit is 'separate' from the others

Comment: Well Java uses signed two's complement for most integer types so typically you are going from -1 to 0.  Going from the highest value to the lowest happens the same way, but there is no bit overflow.  It's when you go from `0111` to `1000`, e.g.

Comment: Im not sure that exactly explains what is happening. It does explain why the operation "wraps around" but underflow/overflow have semantic meaning in the java case. In the processor the case is also "detectable" as well, and can be handled in different ways depending on the needs of the operation (set error bit, etc).

Answer (score 7):

Java loops the number either to the maximum or minimum integer (depending on whether it is overflow or underflow).

So:

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE);
System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

prints true twice.

Answer (score 2):

It basically handles them without reporting an exception, performing the 2's complement arithmetic without concern for overflow or underflow, returning the expected (but incorrect) result based on the mechanics of 2's complement arithmetic.

This means that the bits which over or underflow are simply chopped, and that Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1 typically returns Integer.MAX_VALUE.

As far as "lower order bytes" being a workaround, they really aren't.  What is happening when you use Java bytes to do the arithmetic is that they get expanded into ints, the arithmetic is generally performed on the ints, and the end result is likely to be completely contained in the returned it as it has far more storage capacity than the starting bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think of how java handles overflow/underclock is to picture an anology clock. You can move it forward an hour at a time but eventually the hours will start again. You can wind the clock backward but once you go beyond the start you are at the end again.